# Run grunt task with node.js arguments on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, terminal, gruntjs

I am running into an out of memory error when running grunt babel. It is solved on mac by increasing max-old-space-size. However some of our developers are on windows machines and I have not found a way to do this on windows.

What is the equilevant of:

```
node --max-old-space-size=10000 node_modules/.bin/grunt babel
```

on windows?

Or is there a universal command that works on both?

My dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
"grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-cli": "^1.3.1",
My babel config in gruntfile.js
```

My babel config in gruntfile.

```
babel: {
  options: {
    compact: true,
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
    sourceMap: true,
    inputSourceMap: sourceMapInJson)
  },
},
```

Error I was getting on Mac and still getting on Windows without increasing max-old-space-size:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Error I am getting on Windows with max-old-space-size param:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
         ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: I know that you're asking specifically for windows, I won't be able to help you with that. I just wanted to say, that I had to work on Windows twice (employer requirements) and each time I ended up with setting my own VirtualBox environment with Debian/Ubuntu just for better development experience.

If you cannot solve your problem, maybe try running your software in virtualbox or even in a docker where you can use linux as a base, and then pass the --max-old-space-size argument to node. Setting a command that runs docker and runs all tools you need seems to be an overkill but it will work.

Comment: Is the command failing on Windows?  Does it seem to "work" as in, the command doesn't error out but you still get the error on execution of the task?  If latter, just a shot in the dark but have you tried increasing the max on windows?  Maybe 10,000 was enough on mac but not Windows...

Comment: Are you sure that the command doesn't work on Windows? because, it's supposed to work. I think the same as @klabranche try setting it to a higher value if it doesn't error out.

Also, from the documentation, you can set it as an ENV variable and not have to type it out everytime. - https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

`env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Comment: On windows the command gives out this error: basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
         ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: So I don't believe its because windows requires more memory.Setting env for just command seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Maybe this plugin can helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: @Waltari Is this package useful to you?

Comment: Yes, I would accept it as an answer. We ended up incorporating it into our project. :)

Answer (score 1):

Npm package `increase-memory-limit` would help.

this module fix heap out of memory when running node binaries.

As mentioned in its official [docs](https://npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit)

> it will append --max-old-space-size=4096 in all node calls inside your node_modules/.bin/* files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually this doens't fix it on Windows. There was a communication mismatch with my collegue.

Comment: Can you try `node --max-old-space-size=8192 {name of the file}`?